# will_paginate displays unwanted information in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, will-paginate

I don't know when it's happened, but recently my client noticed strange output in will_paginate's pager. Following fragment of generated views shows unexpected:

```
{"tag"=""
```

in tags properties and very unsightly debug information.

```
<div class="pagination" {"tag"="">
  "Black & White", "action"=>"index", "controller"=>"photos"}="{:order=>nil}">
  <span class="previous_page disabled">← Previous</span>
  <em class="current">1</em>
  <a href="/photos?page=2&tag=Black+%26+White" rel="next">2</a>
  <a class="next_page" href="/photos?page=2&tag=Black+%26+White" rel="next">Next →</a>
</div>
```

my view has following

```
= will_paginate @photos, params=>{:order=>params['order']}
```

I use Ruby ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.16 and  haml 4.0.2

I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it is doing something weird with `params` because you've passed in the variable. I think what you meant to do was this:

```
= will_paginate @photos, :params => {:order=>params['order']}
```

Comment: Fixed, the problem was caused by missing colon.